# How to handle master detail inserts in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, master-detail

I understand that mongo works in an atomic way, and that each creation of a collection works that way, but what happens for example with the typical example of master detail, in which we make references when inserting this Based on the case of relational databases, how does it work in mongo ?, we only insert the data and references with vectors or what is the correct way to work it ?, likewise when we create databases in mongo unique ids are created, how could Then search for matches of them?, Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Two basic options:

1. Insert the data indicating completion at the end. For example, if you have collections A and B, and you query collection A first to identify whether the thing you are looking for is there, and then query B for details, insert into B first and into A second.
2. Use transactions.